# cordova.exec not called in iOS

Tags: ios, cordova-3

I don't know why but the `cordova.exec` is not called in my native code.Could anybody resolve this?
config.xml

```
<widget xmlns     = "url"
    id        = "io.cordova.helloCordova"
    version   = "2.0.0">

    <!-- <content src="url" /> for external pages -->
    <content src="index.html" />

    <feature name="MyHybridBridge">
        <param name="ios-package" value="MyHybridBridge"/>
    </feature>

    <access origin="*"/>
</widget>
```

index.html

```
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
            <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
            <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="master.css" />
            <title>Hello World</title>

            <script>
                function myFunction()
                {
                    MyHybridBridge.updateSliderValue("Hello");
                }
            </script>
        </head>
        <body on

load="init();" id="stage" class="theme">
        <p>Click the button to trigger a function.</p>

        <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>

        <p id="demo"></p>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.1.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="main.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="MyHybridBridge.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="NativeEventsListener.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

MyHybridBridge.js

```
var MyHybridBridge = (function() {
    var PLUGIN_NAME                         = "MyHybridBridge";
    var ACTION_SLIDER_VALUE                 = "ACTION_SLIDER_VALUE";

                      this.updateSliderValue = function (value) {
                      alert("s");
                      cordova.exec(saySuccess, sayFailure, PLUGIN_NAME, ACTION_SLIDER_VALUE, [value]);
                      };
    return this;
}());

function saySuccess() {
    alert("Success");
}

function sayFailure () {
    alert ("Failure");
}
```

MyHybridBridge.m

```
-(void)ACTION_SLIDER_VALUE:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command{
    NSLog(@"ACTION_SLIDER_VALUE");
    CDVPluginResult *pluginResult;

    if (command.arguments.count == 1){
        NSString *title = [command.arguments objectAtIndex:0];
        if ([title isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) title = nil;
        ViewController *viewController = (ViewController*)self.viewController;
        [viewController updateContent:title];
        pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK];
    }
    else {
        pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_ERROR messageAsString:@"Invalid number of parameters"];
    }

    [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:command.callbackId];
}
```

The problem is that `updateSlider` method in `MyHybridBridge.js` is called. Here I am invoking `cordova.exec` method so that `ACTION_SLIDER_VALUE` method in `MyHybridBridge.m` should be called.But I don't know why but this is not being called.Could anybody figure out the problem?
Thanks

Comment: what you mean by not called? do you have a js error?

Comment: -(void)ACTION_SLIDER_VALUE:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command` method is not invoked.I don't get any error neither the method is called in .m file.

Comment: is your plugin registered in config.xml?

Comment: I have updated the question for ur verification.This is how I have added it to config.xml?Is this Correct?